# can't figure out how to properly specialize fmt template on CRTP template classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, fmt

(NOTE: ostream is not an option, do not suggest overloading ostream operators as a solution)
(NOTE: actual working test code that shows each of the attempts is at the bottom)

Basically I have a class heirachy that looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename value_type>
class CRTPBase {
    using CRTPBase_value = value_type;
    ...

}

template<typename T> 
class derived_1: public CRTPBase<derived_1, derived_type_1>{
...
}

template<typename T> 
class derived_2: public CRTPBase<derived_2, derived_type_2>{
...
}

template<typename T> 
class derived_3: public CRTPBase<derived_3, derived_type_3>{
...
}

template<typename T> 
class derived_4: public CRTPBase<derived_4, derived_type_4>{
...
}
```

I want to overload fmt::format for each of the dervied classes, with out duplicating the code for each, as the actual code to print for each type would be exactly the same.

I try first to test with only one of the derived template classes being specialized

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<derived_1<T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const derived_1<T>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, ", ", v(i,j));
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }

};
```

This works perfectly for

```
derived_1 d = ...; 

fmt::print("{}", d);
```

Then I try to see if I can somehow use the CRTP base to specialize

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<CRTPBase<T, T::derived_type>>{
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const CRTPBase<T, T::derived_type>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

This does not work, I get "static assertion failed: don't know how to format the type", there's no valid conversion between the two types, I guess this is because of explicit template conversion issues.  I try then

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<CRTPBase<T, T::derived_type>>{
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

It appears to skip this, I get "static assertion failed: don't know how to format the type", I guess because what ever mechanism fmt uses internally requires the actual formatter type to be present for this to work.

I try then using SFINAE to see if I can do the same

My is_CRTP_derived class looks something like:

```
template<class Derived_T>
using derived_element_wise = decltype(Derived_T::CRTPBase_value);

template<class Derived_T>
using is_CRTP_derived = std::experimental::is_detected<derived_element_wise, Derived_T>
```

The first attempt looks like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U = enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>>
struct fmt::formatter<T>{
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

I get an error about "template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:" Okay, so that doesn't work Next I try

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T,enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>>{
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

Seems to completely skip the type, I get  I get "static assertion failed: don't know how to format the type". So I try

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value, T>>{
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

and I get "error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization" then I try

```
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T>{
    using temp = enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>;
    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
}
```

and I get error: declaration of 'struct fmt::v5::formatter' ambiguates earlier template instantiation for 'struct fmt::v5::formatter'.

And that's were I gave up.  I don't know any other way to actually get this to work How do I avoid doing this for each CRTP derived template class?

EDIT:

Here is actual working code that demonstrates the issue:

```
//main.cpp

#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <type_traits>
//change 0->6 to see errors of each attempt
#define ATTEMPT 0

template<class Derived_T>
using derived_element_wise = decltype(Derived_T::CRTPBase_value);

template<class Derived_T>
using is_CRTP_derived = std::experimental::is_detected<derived_element_wise, Derived_T>;

template<typename T, typename value_type>
struct CRTPBase {
    using CRTPBase_value = value_type;
    std::size_t size(){
        auto derived = static_cast<const T*>(this);
        return derived->width() * derived->height();
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct derived_1: public CRTPBase<derived_1<T>, typename std::remove_const<T>::type>{
    using derived_type = T;
    std::size_t width() const{
        return 1;
    }
    std::size_t height() const{
        return 1;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct derived_2: public CRTPBase<derived_2<T>, typename std::remove_const<T>::type>{
    using derived_type = T;
    std::size_t width() const{
        return 2;
    }
    std::size_t height() const{
        return 2;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct derived_3: public CRTPBase<derived_3<T>, typename std::remove_const<T>::type>{
    using derived_type = T;
    std::size_t width() const{
        return 3;
    }
    std::size_t height() const{
        return 3;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct derived_4: public CRTPBase<derived_4<T>, typename std::remove_const<T>::type>{
    using derived_type = T;
    std::size_t width() const{
        return 4;
    }
    std::size_t height() const{
        return 4;
    }
};



#if ATTEMPT == 0
// Example properly working printer
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<derived_1<T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const derived_1<T>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<derived_2<T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const derived_2<T>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<derived_3<T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const derived_3<T>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<derived_4<T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const derived_4<T>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#elif ATTEMPT == 1
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<CRTPBase<T, typename T::derived_type>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const CRTPBase<T, typename T::derived_type>& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};


#elif ATTEMPT == 2
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<CRTPBase<T, typename T::derived_type>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#elif ATTEMPT == 3
template <typename T, typename U = std::enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>>
struct fmt::formatter<T>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#elif ATTEMPT == 4
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T,std::enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#elif ATTEMPT == 5
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<std::enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value, T>>{

    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#elif ATTEMPT == 6
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<T>{
    using temp = std::enable_if_t<is_CRTP_derived<T>::value>;
    template <typename ParseContext>
    constexpr auto parse(ParseContext& ctx){
        return begin(ctx);
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        auto&& out= ctx.out();
        if(v.height() > 1){
            format_to(out, "[\n");
        }
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v.height(); ++i){
            format_to(out, "[");
            for(std::size_t j = 0; j < v.width(); ++j){
                format_to(out, "{},", 0);
            }
            format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        if(v.height() > 1){
            return format_to(out, "]\n");
        }
        return out;
    }
};
#endif

int main(){
    derived_1<int> d1;
    derived_2<float> d2;
    derived_3<bool> d3;
    derived_4<double> d4;

    fmt::print("{}", d1);
    fmt::print("{}", d2);
    fmt::print("{}", d3);
    fmt::print("{}", d4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<
  T, std::enable_if_t<
       std::is_base_of_v<CRTPBase<T, typename T::derived_type>, T>, char>> {

  auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) { return ctx.begin();}

  template <typename FormatContext>
  auto format(const T& v, FormatContext& ctx) {
    // Format v and write the output to ctx.out().
    return ctx.out();
  }
};
```

Here is a complete working example on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/vsbcc8.

There is also an example of doing this in {fmt} docs: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types.